# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.DBConcurrencyException' occurred

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm a beginner in learning VB.Net with Visual Studio 2008. I have Access (mdb) file integrated to my project.
Currently, I need to update the existing record which call up by using table adapter on DataGridView.

```
 On Error GoTo SaveErr
        Me.AdmissionTblBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.AdmissionTblTableAdapter.Update(MasterTblDataSet.AdmissionTbl)
        MessageBox.Show(txtApplicantFirstName.Text & " " & txtApplicantLastName.Text & " is " & cboInterviewResult.Text & " for the interview")
SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
        Refresh()
```

When I try to run the form, it showed this error. 
 A first chance exception of type `System.Data.DBConcurrencyException` occurred

Looking for help.

Comment: It means a record was changed in two different places (maybe one by your program and the second directly in Access perhaps) and it can't update your changes because there is a conflict.

Comment: How to deal with it? I tried to Update command in other forms for the same table, it showed the same error.

Comment: I solved the problem by change the 'On Error GoTo SaveErr' to 'On Error GoTo Resume' and the problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by change the 'On Error GoTo SaveErr' to 'On Error GoTo Resume' and the problem solved. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that solved the issue and didn't just "skip over"  it? I'd validate that your data looks as expected because this seems like the absolute wrong answer

Comment: I solved it by check back my database structure and Update command. The error appeared when it saved an empty value to the DB.